# How can i change the value in my array list from user input?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an arraylist which is below in my ShoeLibrary class. I also have another class called Shoe which has the setters and getters for the variables in this array list.

**ShoeLibrary Class**

```
public class ShoeLibrary {

private ArrayList<Shoe> shoes;

public ShoeLibrary() {
    shoes = new ArrayList<Shoe>();
    shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 1", 100)); // the integer represents stock
    shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 2", 200));
    shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 3", 300));
}
```

In my MainActivity GUI class i have a input dialog which takes user input of integer value and then adds it to the basket.

I need a way to update the number (stock) in the array list when the user enters this value. How would i do this.

Comment: Is 'Shoe 1' a type and 100 is the quantity? If so then you want to get the shoe from the list and then use a setter in the Shoe class to change the quantity. If this is what you're talking about then I can provide some help with the code.

Comment: @ChrisSharp yes thats correct

Comment: Was the answer below helpful or you're did I answer the wrong question?

Comment: @ChrisSharp yes it was thanks.

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer, if it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that my comment was correct and written some basic code to show you how this is done. You need to change this to fit your situation and get the customer data from your GUI. You also need to do error checking.

```
public class Sandbox { //opens class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Shoe>shoes = new ArrayList<Shoe>();
        shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 1", 100)); // the integer represents stock
        shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 2", 200));
        shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 3", 300));
        Shoe temp;
        String shoeSelected = "Shoe 3"; // you need to use the customer's input here
        int numSeleted = 20; // again, you need this data from the customer input
        for (int i = 0; i < shoes.size(); i++) {
            temp = shoes.get(i);
            if(temp.name == shoeSelected) {
                shoes.get(i).setQuantity(temp.quantity - numSeleted);
                System.out.println(shoes.get(i).name);
                System.out.println(shoes.get(i).quantity);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("wait");
    }

}

class Shoe {
    String name;
    int quantity;

    public Shoe(String name, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you put the arraylist and the code in the main method?

Comment: Because I have no idea how your classes are set up nor do I have your GUI interface. I put it there so I could demonstrate to you how you would go about modifying items in the list. The call and list can come from anywhere.